# How to set custom lookback in TA-Lib Pattern Recognition for Python

Tags: ta-lib

I'm trying to set a custom lookback period of 3 Candles for CDLHANGINGMAN. Reading the documentation of abstract function I can see that the default Lookback period is 11, using 
`Function('CDLHANGINGMAN').lookback`
I want to change it to 3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't change timeperiod for candle functions. They're depend on default values of candle types. But there is a function in C++ interface to change these defaults: `TA_SetCandleSettings()`. And there is a code in Python wrapper of this lib that wraps that function. It's introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/commit/d25e9dfe35ceecf71d888661c8f1c8bba805d3fd) in 0.4.14. [Here is](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/113#issuecomment-305353650) the example on how to call it from python.
Timeperiod for CDLHANGINGMAN is

```
max( max( max( TA_CANDLEAVGPERIOD(BodyShort), TA_CANDLEAVGPERIOD(ShadowLong) ),
                     TA_CANDLEAVGPERIOD(ShadowVeryShort) ),
                TA_CANDLEAVGPERIOD(Near)
            ) + 1;
```

So you need to make sure that `avgperiod` for candle types BodyShort, ShadowLong, ShadowVeryShort and Near is <= 2. But as there is no function that changes only `avgperiod` and it sets all 3 `rangetype, avgperiod, factor` that seems not to be easy to do. The list of current default values for all candle types you can find [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_common/ta_global.c#l144).